# MongoDB C# driver - Filter list of array based on specific item id

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am new to using MongoDB C# driver. I have the following in my MongoDB collection. I need to filter the record based on `_id` something like:

```
Select * from item where _id = 2 and itemLists.Sizeid = 2
```

in SQL.

I tried like:

```cs
var filter = Builders<Item>.Filter.Eq(x => x.temid, ItemId);
var filter2 = Builders<Item>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.itemLists, Builders<ItemList>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Sizeid,sizeId));

var data = await Context.GetCollection<Item>("Item").Find(filter&filter2).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

The above code is not giving me the expected result. Kindly help.

My MongoDB collection data is as below:-

```
{
    "_id" : NumberInt(2),
    "ItemName" : "Shirt",
    "ItemDescripton" : "Men Trouser",
    "itemLists" : [
        {
            "CategoryId" : NumberInt(1),
            "CategpryName" : "Men",
            "ColorId" : NumberInt(1),
            "ColorName" : "Red",
            "InitialQty" : NumberInt(30),
            "AvailableQty" : NumberInt(28),
            "ReserveQty" : NumberInt(2),
            "Price" : 4560.0,
            "OfferPrice" : 670.0,
            "Images" : [
                "/assets/Images/Men/m4.jpg",
                "/assets/Images/Men/m5.jpg"
            ],
            "Sizeid" : NumberInt(2),
            "SizeName" : "XL",
            "DetailId" : NumberInt(0),
            "DeliveryCharges" : NumberInt(20),
            "Brand" : "Allen Solly",
            "CreatedOn" : ISODate("2022-12-07T17:10:19.881+0000"),
            "CreatedBy" : "string",
            "Active" : true
        },
        {
            "CategoryId" : NumberInt(1),
            "CategpryName" : "Men",
            "ColorId" : NumberInt(2),
            "ColorName" : "Blue",
            "InitialQty" : NumberInt(10),
            "AvailableQty" : NumberInt(6),
            "ReserveQty" : NumberInt(4),
            "Price" : 1400.0,
            "OfferPrice" : 1200.0,
            "Images" : [
                "/assets/Images/Men/m3.jpg",
                "/assets/Images/Men/m4.jpg"
            ],
            "Sizeid" : NumberInt(1),
            "SizeName" : "XL",
            "DetailId" : NumberInt(0),
            "DeliveryCharges" : NumberInt(120),
            "Brand" : "Allen Solly",
            "CreatedOn" : ISODate("2022-12-07T17:10:19.881+0000"),
            "CreatedBy" : "string",
            "Active" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `Item` class? Have you applied `[BsonElement("_id")]` or `[BsonId]` attribute to `ItemId` property?

Comment: public class Item
{

      [BsonId]
      [BsonElement("_id")]
      public int Itemid { get; set; }
      public string ItemName { get; set; }
      public string ItemDescripton { get; set; }
      public List<ItemList> itemLists { get; set; }
}

Comment: I test your code is working. Try to remove the filter to see whether it is able to return data. Do you check your data really exist in the collection?

Comment: Data exists in collection but it is not filtering data based on sizeid and itemid.  I am not getting filtered data.  It is returning complete document.

Comment: Expected output

{
  "temid": 2,
  "itemName": "Shirt",
  "itemDescripton": "Men Trouser",
  "itemLists": [
    {
      "categoryId": 1,
      "categpryName": "Men",
      "colorId": 1,
      "colorName": "Red",
      "initialQty": 30,
      "availableQty": 28,
      "reserveQty": 2,
      "price": 4560,
      "offerPrice": 670,
      "images": [
        "/assets/Images/Men/m4.jpg",
        "/assets/Images/Men/m5.jpg"
      ],
      "sizeid": 2,
      "sizeName": "XL",
      "deliveryCharges": 20,
      "brand": "Allen Solly",
      
    }
  
  ]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question and comments, you are expecting the queried document to be filtered with the `itemLists` array for the `sizeId` criteria.

You need a `ProjectionDefinition` with `ElemMatch` in order to achieve it.

```cs
ProjectionDefinition<Item> projection = Builders<Item>.Projection
    .Include(x => x.Itemid)
    .Include(x => x.ItemName)
    .Include(x => x.ItemDescripton)
    .ElemMatch(x => x.itemLists, Builders<ItemList>.Filter.Eq(y => y.Sizeid, sizeId));

var data = await _collection.Find(filter & filter2)
    .Project<Item>(projection)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

> Demo

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.  Appreciate your help and support in this regard.